# How can I check the progress of matrix multiplication?

Tags: cuda

I'm now only need to show an intermediate progress of matrix multiplication.

```
for(unsigned int col=0; col<mtxSize; col++) {
         unsigned tmp = 0;
         for(unsigned int row=0; row<mtxSize; row++) {
             for(unsigned int idx=0; idx<mtxSize; idx++) {
                 tmp += h_A[col*mtxSize+idx] * h_B[idx*mtxSize+row];
            }
             h_Rs[col*mtxSize+row] = tmp;
             tmp = 0;
             int rate_tmp = (col*mtxSize + (row+1))*100;
             // Maybe like this...
             fprintf(stdout, "Progress : %d.%d %%\r", rate_tmp/actMtxSize, rate_tmp%actMtxSize);
             fflush(stdout);
         }
}
```

In the case of the host code(use CPU), it is very easy beacause it process sequentially so we can check very easily.

But in the case of the GPU which process in parallel, what should I do?

Once the kernel is running, it does not return until finish the kernel execution.

So I can't check mid-data during the kernel execution time.

I think I need to use asynchronous kernel call, but I do not know well.

And even if the asynchronous kernel call is used, to see all of the data into several blocks over processors, do I have to write atomicAdd() (in other words, global memory access)  function which is including some overhead?

Give me some advice or hint.

And I want to know in the case of CUDA.

Comment: If you only want to check the data, you still have the ability to debug the code (for cuda) with the nsight visual studio or nsight eclipse edition. For opencl there are also debuggers, too - don't know  excact about it, because I develop for cuda.

Comment: hubs // The data I mean was the number of element which are computed completely. Using the data I can calculate the rate of progress.

Comment: Yes, but in the provided code you only output the rate. So I thought you'll only need it for debugging. Do you need it for following computations, too?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I'm going to make progress bar using GUI.

Comment: So for CUDA you only can split it into several kernels. For example a kernel is computing a row or several rows, because you have no influence how the sheduler works and in which order the theadblocks are computed.

Comment: I can answer this for CUDA but not for OpenCL.  If you write questions that demand answers across a variety of domains, they are going to be more difficult to answer.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry Robert. I will keep in mind that.

Comment: I edited my question and domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a code which demonstrates how to check progress from a matrix multiply kernel:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TIME_INC 100000000
#define INCS 10
#define USE_PROGRESS 1
#define MAT_DIMX 4000
#define MAT_DIMY MAT_DIMX

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void mykernel(volatile int *data){

  unsigned long time;
  for (int i = 0; i < INCS; i++){
    atomicAdd((int *)data,1);
    __threadfence_system();
    time = clock64();
    while((clock64() - time)<TIME_INC) {};
    }
  printf("progress check finished\n");
}

__global__ void matmult(float *a, float *b, float *c, unsigned int rowA, unsigned int colA, unsigned int colB, volatile int *progress){
  unsigned int row = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  unsigned int col = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
  if ((row < rowA) && (col < colB)){
    float temp = 0.0f;
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < colA; k++)
      temp += a[(row*colA)+k] * b[(k*colB) + col];
    c[(row*colB)+col] = temp;
#if USE_PROGRESS
    if (!(threadIdx.x || threadIdx.y)){
      atomicAdd((int *)progress, 1);
      __threadfence_system();
      }
#endif
  }
}

int main(){
// simple test to demonstrate reading progress data from kernel
  volatile int *d_data, *h_data;
  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaSetDeviceFlags error");
  cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h_data, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostAlloc error");
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((int **)&d_data, (int *)h_data, 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostGetDevicePointer error");
  *h_data = 0;
  printf("kernel starting\n");
  mykernel<<<1,1>>>(d_data);
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  int value = 0;
  do{
    int value1 = *h_data;
    if (value1 > value){
       printf("h_data = %d\n", value1);
       value = value1;}}
    while (value < (INCS-1));
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail 2");

// now try matrix multiply with progress

  float *h_c, *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
  h_c = (float *)malloc(MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float));
  if (h_c == NULL) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc a fail");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc b fail");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc c fail");

  for (int i = 0; i < MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY; i++) h_c[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_c, MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy a fail");
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_c, MAT_DIMX*MAT_DIMY*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy b fail");

  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  *h_data=0;
  dim3 block(16,16);
  dim3 grid(((MAT_DIMX+block.x-1)/block.x), ((MAT_DIMY+block.y-1)/block.y));
  printf("matrix multiply kernel starting\n");
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  matmult<<<grid,block>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, MAT_DIMY, MAT_DIMX, MAT_DIMX, d_data);
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
#if USE_PROGRESS
  unsigned int num_blocks = grid.x*grid.y;
  float my_progress = 0.0f;
  value = 0;
  printf("Progress:\n");
  do{
    cudaEventQuery(stop);  // may help WDDM scenario
    int value1 = *h_data;
    float kern_progress = (float)value1/(float)num_blocks;
    if ((kern_progress - my_progress)> 0.1f) {
      printf("percent complete = %2.1f\n", (kern_progress*100));
      my_progress = kern_progress;}}
    while (my_progress < 0.9f);
  printf("\n");
#endif
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaCheckErrors("event sync fail");
  float et;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  cudaCheckErrors("event elapsed time fail");
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("mat mult kernel fail");
  printf("matrix multiply finished.  elapsed time = %f milliseconds\n", et);


  return 0;
}
```

The code associated with the first kernel call  is just to demonstrate the basic idea of having a kernel report it's progress back.

The second part of the code shows a sample, naive matrix multiply on the GPU, with the GPU reporting it's progress back.  I have included the ability to remove the progress check code via a preprocessor macro, as well as the ability to time the matrix multiply kernel. For the case I have here, there was no discernible difference in timing with or without the progress code.  So while the progress reporting code probably does add *some* overhead, when compared to the scope of a reasonable sized matrix multiply kernel, it adds no significant time that I can see.

Some other uses of signalling are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385530/reading-global-flag-does-not-work-for-cpugpu-data-exchange-in-cuda)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'll test my program this way. And I felt I've been using only the familiar API for me, because I have never used this two API (cudaHostAllocMapped, cudaHostGetDevicePointer). It seems that I just need to study with your code. Thanks!

Comment: The value `*h_data` never changes on my machine.  With Nsight, I can see the atomicAdd working as the value grows in the kernel, but it is not reflected when reading in the host code.  Is TCC required for this?  I expected this to work on my GTX 980, but it never leaves the do-while loop.

Comment: I think it works correctly on linux (just tested it again) and I think it should work similarly on windows TCC. Windows WDDM may present some challenges that I hadn't anticipated when I wrote it. Sometimes special steps are needed in WDDM mode such as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455396). I'm not suggesting that is an explanation for any difficulties with this code in WDDM, I merely point out that there may be some additional requirements for it to work under WDDM. I don't have a WDDM machine conveniently available ATM to test, but if time permits I'll take a look.

Comment: Well shoot, it works with a `cudaEventQuery`.  I feel dirty doing it though.  :)  Thanks for the tip.  Is this a bug/bugworthy issue, or simply to be expected with non-TCC or Geforce devices.?

Comment: You're welcome to file bugs or requests for enhancement.  It's not clear to me that it is definitely a bug. While I might like different behavior in WDDM, what is happening sort of makes sense to me. When I looked at it briefly under WDDM it did seem like it might just need a queue flush, but that seems inconsistent with your reported observation in nsight. But I haven't taken a close look.

Comment: It seems to me like `volatile` does not defeat cache like one would expect, when dealing with pinned memory under WDDM.  The `atomicAdd` functions as designed from the point of view of the kernel, but the value definitely does not become visible to the host (volatile used in both host and device functions).  The query updates the host value.  I tried using WC flag in addition to Mapped, but it didn't help.

Comment: I've updated the code (added one line) which seems to help under windows WDDM, I get expected output with RTX2070, CUDA 10.1, driver 432.00, win10.

Comment: Some folks [report](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/why-cudamemcpyasync-has-different-behaviors-on-different-cpu-platforms/231414) being happier with work scheduling on the WDDM GPU with the [hardware scheduling feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/hardware-accelerated-gpu-scheduling/) turned on.