# CUDA mapped memory: device -> host writes are not visible on host

Tags: cuda

What I was trying to do is modifying a variable which resides in mapped memory that would cause the main program to exit.

But instead of this the main program keeps spinning on `while (var == 0) ;` line. I don't know how the new value could be flushed out so it would be visible on the host side too.

Btw. the variable is declared as `volatile` everywhere and I tried using the `__threadfence_system()` function with no success.

The host -> device direction works well.

System: Windows 7 x64, driver 358.50, GTX 560

Here is the piece of code that I can't get working:

```
static void handleCUDAError(cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(err) (handleCUDAError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

__global__ void echoKernel(volatile int* semaphore)
{
    *semaphore = 1;

    __threadfence_system();
}

int main()
{
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaSetDevice(0));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost));

    volatile int var = 0;
    volatile int *devptr;

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostRegister((int*)&var, sizeof (int), cudaHostRegisterMapped));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&devptr, (int*)&var, 0));

    echoKernel <<< 1, 1 >>> (devptr);

    while (var == 0) ;

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostUnregister((int*)&var));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your code on linux, it runs as-is without issue.

However on windows, there is a problem around WDDM command batching.  In effect, your kernel does not launch and is not getting launched before you enter the while-loop that hangs.

The WDDM command queue is a queue of commands that will eventually go to the GPU device.  Various events will cause this queue to be "flushed" and the contents to be delivered as a "batch" of commands to the GPU.

Various cuda runtime API calls may effectively force the "flushing" of the command queue, such as `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaMemcpy()`.  However after the kernel launch, you are not issuing any runtime API calls before entering your while-loop.  As a result, in this scenario it seems that the kernel call is getting "stuck" in the queue and never "flushed".

You can work around this in a variety of ways, for example by recording an event after the launch of the kernel and then querying the status of that event.  This will have the effect of flushing the queue, which will launch the kernel.

Here's an example modification of your code that works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void handleCUDAError(cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(err) (handleCUDAError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

__global__ void echoKernel(volatile int* semaphore)
{
    *semaphore = 1;

    __threadfence_system();
}

int main()
{
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaSetDevice(0));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost));

    volatile int var = 0;
    volatile int *devptr;

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostRegister((int*)&var, sizeof(int), cudaHostRegisterMapped));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&devptr, (int*)&var, 0));

    cudaEvent_t my_event;
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&my_event));

    echoKernel << < 1, 1 >> > (devptr);
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaEventRecord(my_event));
    cudaEventQuery(my_event);

    while (var == 0);

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaHostUnregister((int*)&var));
    CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on CUDA 7.5, Driver 358.50, Win7 x64 release project, GTX460M.

Note that we don't wrap the `cudaEventQuery` call in a standard error checker, because the expected behavior for it is to return a non-zero status when the event has not been completed yet.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! That's a bit of strange. I supposed that device -> host transfers are buffered somehow, but fortunately this is not the case. The solution you proposed works nicely.